# GoogleSheets Array Formula with importrange vlookup error

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I will try to explain my question as better as possible

I need to verify on another worksheet using importrange if the values under column J match column AN on the imported range

This needs to match any row and make it as unique values

The idea is to get a Company name from matching column J to AN

=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(J:J, IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet_url", "sheet_name!AN:AN"), 0)), VLOOKUP(J:J, IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet_url", "sheet_name!AN:A"), 1, FALSE), ""))

This is what I came up with, although it says value from column J not found for all lines

Any suggestions?
I want to avoid using appscripts

Explained above, if more information is needed I will inform